What does the continuity property of charge implies?
Let $f:(0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ be a function. For $a,b\in[0,1],a<b$ let's define $\mu((a,b])=f(a+)-f(b+)$ and naturally extend $\mu$ to a charge on the family of finite unions of these kind of intervals $\mathcal{F}$ (charge is like a content, but not necessarily nonnegative). If one wants charge to satisfy the continuity property, what kind of properties are necessary for $f$ to have.
I guess its easy to see that $f$ must be bounded and right-continuous, but I'm very curious about the other properties.
Btw, when I say continuity property, I think of this:
If $A_n$ is a decreasing sequence of sets in $\mathcal{F}$ and $\bigcap_n A_n=\emptyset$, then $\lim_n \mu(A_n)=0$.
Edit: Such functions might be of bounded variation. The reason I say that is because $f$ can be e.g. Hölder continuous and its charge non-continuous. To prove this, first consult the proposition 2.3.2 in Theory of charges (K.P.S. Bhaskara Rao, M. Bhaskara Rao). It says that if a charge on a field of sets has the continuity property, then it's a measure ($\sigma$-additive) on the field. This means that if a decreasing sequence of positive numbers $(a_n)_n$ that tends to $0$ must have a property:
$$\sum_n |f(a_n)-f(a_{n+1})|<\infty$$
Why? Because if we want $\mu((0,a_1])=\sum_n\mu((a_{n+1},a_n])$, the sum on the right side must not depend on the ordering of the sets, i.e. it must converge absolutely. This is probably not the case for general Hölder continuous functions. Namely, only bound we have is $|f(a_n)-f(a_{n+1})|\leq c|a_n-a_{n+1}|^\alpha$ which can easily be manipulated to diverge when in sum. However, actually creating this function might be difficult. All in all, function being Lipschitz would satisfy the condition above and perhaps being of bounded variation might also be enough.

As I understand your notation, for any $a\in [0,1)$, $f(a+)=\lim_{b\to a,\, b>a} f(b)$ and $f$ is right-continuous at $a$, if $f(a)=f(a+)$. Since in the definition of the charge $\mu$ are used the limit values of $f$, the values of $\mu$ will not change if we change the values of $f$ at finitely many points. So, the function $f$ can fail to be right-continuous. To fix this issue, we put $\bar f(a)=f(a+)$. The value of $\bar f(1)$ can be arbitrary (anyway, $f(1+)$ is undefined). Then $\mu((a,b])=\bar f(a)- \bar f(b)$ for any $a,b\in[0,1],a<b$, so in this answer we are going to study the necessary properties of the function $\bar f$ instead of those of the function $f$.
It is easy to check that the function $\bar f$ is right-continuous at any point $a\in [0,1)$.
Since the image of $f$ is contained in $[0,1]$, the image of $\bar f$ is contained in $[0,1]$ too, so the function $\bar f$ is trivially bounded. But the latter can fail when we relax the first condition to that $f$ and $\bar f$ are real-valued functions. Indeed, given $x\in [0,1]$ put $f(x)=0$, if $x=1$ and $f(x)=k$, if $x\in \left[1-2^{-k},1-2^{-k-1}\right)$ for some nonnegative integer $k$. Note that the function $f$ is right-continuous and so $\bar f(x)=f(x)$ for each $x\in [0,1)$. Now let $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be any decreasing sequence of sets in $\mathcal{F}$ such that $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} A_n=\varnothing$. Therefore there exists a natural number $N$ such that $0\not\in A_N$. Let $X=\{1-2^{-k}:k\in\mathbb N\}$. Since $A_N\in\mathcal F$, the set $A_N\cap X$ is finite. Since the sequence $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is decreasing and $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} A_n=\varnothing$, there exists a natural number $N'$ such that the set $A_{N'}\cap X=\varnothing$. Then for each natural $n\ge N'$, each interval $I$ constituting the set $A_n$ contains no points of $X$, so $\mu(I)=0$, and thus $\mu(A_n)=0$ too. Therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu(A_n)=0$.
Thus we have to keep the condition that the image of $\bar f$ is contained in $[0,1]$. But even in this case the function $\bar f$ can fail to have the bounded variation. The example is similar to that from the previous paragraph, but in this case, given $x\in [0,1]$ put $f(x)=0$, if $x=1$ and $f(x)=(-1)^k$, if $x\in \left[1-2^{-k},1-2^{-k-1}\right)$ for some nonnegative integer $k$.
Even a monotone bounded function $f$ can be rather bad. For instance for any enumeration $e$ of the set $\mathbb Q'=\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$ then similarly to the above we can show that the function $f(x)=\sum_{r\le x,\,r\in\mathbb Q'} 2^{-e(r)}$ from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$ fits.
